# How to use fetch in a Sapper project outside of routes?

Tags: svelte, sapper

In Sapper it's possible to use `this.fetch` in the `preload()` function inside `<script context="module">`. Sapper then figures out whether to use the client or server version of `fetch`.

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload() {
        const res = await this.fetch(`something.json`);
    }
</script>
```

Writing all your requests in your routes doesn't scale well so it becomes a necessity to create an `api` service to do something like:

```
<script context="module">
    import {getJson} from 'api';

    export async function preload() {
        const res = await getJson();
    }
</script>
```

This creates a problem since outside of the `preload()` function there is no `this` context provided by Sapper and hence no `this.fetch` available when running in the Node context (when loading the first page of the application and doing SSR). Afterwards all requests are made from the browser so regular `fetch` is available.

A solution could be to use an HTTP client for Node like `node-fetch` in the api service and then determine at runtime with `process.browser` if we need to use `fetch` or `node-fetch`.

Is there a better way to overcome this Sapper limitation?

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@beyonk/sapper-httpclient which I wrote for this exact purpose. It does what Stephane suggests below.

Comment: Thanks @AntonyJones ! I moved from Sapper to an SPA with code splitting because it became too complicated dealing with cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you came up with is the most common one.
An alternative would be to pass `this.fetch` as an argument along others to the the getJson method:

```
<script context="module">
    import {getJson} from 'api';

    export async function preload() {
        const res = await getJson(this.fetch);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.fetch` is meant to be used only in routes (think `asyncData` in Nuxt).
Using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a common solution too, as it allows to write code that execute the same in both environments without patching `fetch` (like you would with `node-fetch`).